# Grails Project not shown in NetBeans project window

Tags: grails, netbeans

I create a new Grails project from NetBeans but when I complete the project complition wizard, nothing to show in my NetBeans project window. My details configuration is:

NetBeans 8.0.2, JDK 8 64bit, Grails 3.0.1

I check my environment veriable setting for Java & Grails also. Everything seems ok, and one important thing is in command line when I type `grails -version`, it shows the version name and so on. I uninstall NetBeans, JDK, & Grails several times but same problem, I also try it for JDK 1.7 32 bit, no result. I'm used to with NetBeans, so I don't try to other IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look where the project is defined on disk and open it into NetBeans.

Comment: It's also possible that NetBeans doesn't support Grails 3.0.1.

Comment: yes @ Geertjan Wielenga you are right, netbeans 8.0.2 does'nt support grails 3.0.1. it support grails 2.3. i fix the problem. Thanks a lot....

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how this case was solved, but to me it looks like the problem is still valid:

The New Project wizard (Groovy -> Grails Application) calls "grails create-app" but does not generate the nbproject directory.

My environment is:
NetBeans: 8.0.2; Grails Version: 3.0.4; Groovy Version: 2.4.4; JVM Version: 1.7.0_79

Comment: Netbeans Grails support doesn't work on latest version of Grails (3.0.4). Last working version is Grails 2.5.

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=254336

Answer (score 0):

`Netbeans 8.0.*` does not have support for `Grails 3.*` projects. It can create project but cannot recognize and open the project since the project structure has been dramatically changed from Grails 2.* to 3.*.  There was a [task](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=254405) created to resolve this problem. Now it reads `VERIFIED FIXED` for version `8.1`. So **[please upgrade to `Netbeans 8.1.*`](https://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html)** in order to be able to handle `Grails 3.*` projects in Netbeans.